# Complex django query in a many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=140)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    favorites    = models.ManyToManyField(Book, null=True, blank=True)
    user         = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

I need to craete a list of all books and show which ones are favorites and which ones are not.

I need a queryset for a view that gets me all the books like

```
Book.objects.all()
```

but i also need to know for each book if it is a favorite for that user and then pass this queryset to the template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relatively straightforward use of the ManyToManyField.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=140)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    favorites    = models.ManyToManyField(Book, null=True, blank=True)
    user         = models.OneToOneField(User)

favorite_books = this_user_profile.favorites.all()
for b in Book.objects.all():
    if b in favorite_books:
        print "Book", b.name, "is a favorite of this user!"
    else:
        print "Book", b.name, "is not a favorite of this user!"
```

ETA: Since you say you want to add it to the template, give it to the template as a list of tuples.

```
book_list = [(b, (b in favorite_books)) for b in Book.objects.all()]
```

In your template, have the code

```
{% for book, is_favorite in book_list %}
    {% if is_favorite %}
        {% comment %} Do something with this favorite book {% endcomment %}
    {% else %}
        {% comment %} Do something with this non favorite book {% endcomment %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe my question isn't very crear but I neet to pass it to the template insted of printing and that's where I have the issue. How do I add this extra info to the queryset?